# Theorem by Jacobi which counts the number of integer solutions to an $x^2+y^2=n$

Tags: number-theory

In this [quora answer](https://qr.ae/pGC8Sj), the following theorem is stated: For integers $(x,y)$, the number of solutions for,

$$x^2 +y^2 =n$$

Is given as : $| \{ (x,y):x^2 +y^2 = n \} |= 4 \left[ d_1(n) - d_3(n) \right]$

It is said that the above theorem is by Jacobi.

What is the exact name of this theorem and where can I find a proof for it?

One of the commenters claimed a high school level proof is possible

Comment: It's (sometimes) known as the Jacobi Two squares theorem. [Try this link for a simple proof](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~mikeh/webpapers/paper21.pdf) via generating functions (but it's not simple enough for high school level).

Comment: Thank you ^^ @CalvinLin

Comment: For more than you ever wanted to know about this see [OEIS sequence A004018](https://oeis.org/A004018).

Comment: it is in Dickson's little book, https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.466075